# extracting age variations using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = '18year old 23 year old 99 years old but not 25-year-old and 91year old cousin is 99 now and 90-year-old or 102 year old'
```

From `s`, I would like to extract all ages that are 90 or greater using regex. For instance, `99 years old` would be extracted but not `18year old`.

I have tried the following

```
    reg = r'(9\d|\d{3,})(-year-old)|(9\d|\d{3,})( year old)'
    r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
    r1
```

Which gives me

```
[('90', '-year-old', '', ''), ('', '', '102', ' year old')]
```

Ideally, I would like this output

```
['99 years old', '91year old', '90-year-old',  '102 year old' ]
```

How do I alter my regex `reg` to get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will do what you want:

```
(?:9\d|1\d{2})(?:\s|-)?years?(?:\s|-)?old
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rRB0HU/1)

**Explanation:**

```
(?:9\d|1\d{2})     # Non-capturing group - match 9x or 1xx
(?:\s|-)?          # Non-capturing group - optionally match whitespace or -
years?             # Match year and optionally s
(?:\s|-)?          # Non-capturing group - optionally match whitespace or -
old                # Match old
```

**Code snippet:**

```
reg = r'(?:9\d|1\d{2})(?:\s|-)?years?(?:\s|-)?old'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
print(r1)
# ['99 years old', '91year old', '90-year-old', '102 year old']
```