# modification of extracting age variations using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
    import re
    s = '99year old 93yo 100 yo 97y.o. and his wife is 93 y.o. 20 y.o  90old 23 year old 29 years old but not 25-year-old and 91year old cousin is 99 now and 90-year-old or 102 year old'
    reg = r'(?:9\d|1\d{2})(?:\s|-)?years?(?:\s|-)?old'
    r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
    r1
    ['99year old', '91year old', '90-year-old', '102 year old']
```

The following code works well and is taken from [extracting age variations using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210909/extracting-age-variations-using-regex)

My goal is to extract the elements listed in `r1` plus any digit ***above 90*** ending with `y.o.` or `yo`. My desired output is

```
 ['99year old', '93yo', '100 yo', '97y.o., '93 y.o.',  '91year old', '90-year-old', '102 year old']
```

I have tried to alter `reg` as follows but this doesn't quiet work

```
reg = r'(?:9\d|1\d{2})(?:\s|-)?years?(?:\s|-)?old(?:9\d|1\d{2})y.o.|(?:9\d|1\d{2})yo'
```

How do I alter `reg` to get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe some expression similar to,

```
\b(?:9\d|1\d{2})\s*-?y(?:ears?)?\.?\s*-?o(?:ld)?\.?\b
```

might be OK to look into.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'\b(?:9\d|1\d{2})\s*-?y(?:ears?)?\.?\s*-?o(?:ld)?\.?\b'
string = '''
99year old 93yo 100 yo 97y.o. and his wife is 93 y.o. 20 y.o  90old 23 year old 29 years old but not 25-year-old and 91year old cousin is 99 now and 90-year-old or 102 year old
'''

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

#### Output

> ['99year old', '93yo', '100 yo', '97y.o', '93 y.o', '91year old',
>   '90-year-old', '102 year old']

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hMbTXi/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/hMbTXi/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---